# Angular import and export constants

Tags: angular

I'm working on this tutorial and there seems to be some issues with the code or the version I'm using.

I'm trying to import the constants.
However, it's not finding the constants. There are red lines under
arrGender: Array;,
arrOccupation: Array;
etc

```
//3. import all constants
import {
    Occupations,
    JobTypes,
    Genders,
    Hobbies,
    MartialStatuses,
    ResidentTypes,
    Qualifications
} from './constData';

    export class PersonalInformationComponent implements OnInit {
    // 7a. Define the properties for databinding
    person: Person;
    persons: Array<Person>;
    arrGender: Array;
    arrOccupation: Array<Occupations>;
    arrJobType: Array<JobTypes>;
    arrQualification: Array<Qualifications>;
    arrHobbies: Array<Hobbies>;
    arrMartialStatus: Array<MartialStatuses>;
    arrResidentialType: Array<ResidentTypes>;
    canChange: boolean; 
    canEdit: boolean;
    tableHeaders: Array;

    constructor(private pServ: PersonalInfoService) {
        this.canChange = false;
        this.canEdit = false;
        this.tableHeaders = new Array();
        this.person = new Person();
        this.persons = new Array();
        this.arrGender = new Array();
    }
```

Comment: "this tutorial" means what exactly? ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are error messages related to the red lines. They would be very helpful for the investigation.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1395/cosmosdb-webapi-angular-client

Cannot find "Genders" "Occupations" etc..

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: @JasonJay look at the data you should have a folder named constData, in that folder there should be an index.ts, in that index.ts it should export the interfaces, classes whatever.  In the constData folder there should also be a list of files and in them that have exports named.  you might have a file named gender.ts and in that file there should be some export interface... Do you see anything like that?  if not that is why you're getting the red underline.

Comment: I have a folder called app and within that folder is constData.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I still get the same error. Go to https://angular-v5fn3l.stackblitz.io

Comment: @JasonJay your stackblitz is messed up. You don't understand the core concept of Angular, or JS in general. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5fn3l

Comment: @ChauTran Yes, I agree with that statement. That is why I'm working on tutorial. doh!
Why are my constants not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//3. import all constants
import {
    Occupations,
    JobTypes,
    Genders,
    Hobbies,
    MartialStatuses,
    ResidentTypes,
    Qualifications
} from './constData';

export class PersonalInformationComponent implements OnInit {
  // 7a. Define the properties for databinding
  person: Person;
  persons: Array<Person>;
  // You forgot to add the type to the Array here...
  arrGender: Array<Gender>;
  arrOccupation: Array<Occupations>;
  arrJobType: Array<JobTypes>;
  arrQualification: Array<Qualifications>;
  arrHobbies: Array<Hobbies>;
  arrMartialStatus: Array<MartialStatuses>;
  arrResidentialType: Array<ResidentTypes>;
  canChange: boolean; 
  canEdit: boolean;
  // You forgot to add the type to the Array here...
  tableHeaders: Array<string>;

  constructor(private pServ: PersonalInfoService) {
    this.canChange = false;
    this.canEdit = false;
    this.tableHeaders = new Array();
    this.person = new Person();
    this.persons = new Array();
    this.arrGender = new Array();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did add the types but it still says it cannot find the types.
Take a look at this. https://angular-v5fn3l.stackblitz.io